# update table on checking some other table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write the single query for this pseudo code.

```
 if(entry exist in table A){
 return 'Some Message A'
 }
 else if(entry exist in table B){
 return 'Some message B'
 }
 else update table C set field A = CASE 
 When field b = 0 then 1
 Else 0
 End 
 return 'Done'
```

Comment: A query cannot both "return" a value and execute an `update`.

Comment: there is no any `return 'Done'` in mysql. do you use any language to connect to DB ?

Comment: This logic can be implemented in your application code.

Comment: if I use select returnMessage if Exist (select query for table A) THEN 'Some Message A'

Comment: You need a stored procedure

Comment: I Have achieved the half way.I want to ask if there is a way to have update in sub query?        CASE SYNTAX...WHEN (UPDATE `tbl_categories` SET `catName` = 'Income8', `catType` = '1', `catPId` = '0', `catStatus` = '1', catModifiedDate = NOW(), `is_changed` = '1'
WHERE `catId` = '11264'
AND `catUsrId` = '99993') THEN 'Done'
    ELSE 'Can Not Proceed'
    END as Message